# Customize URL SEO

Tags: url-rewriting

I have link www.mydomain.com/page.php?pageid=10

I want to change into www.mydomain.com/10

please help me this guys.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a .htaccess file, and place it in the webroot.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ page.php?pageid=10
```